# How to define a Google Cloud Function with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to setup a NodeJS function using Google Cloud Function (GCF) in typescript. I am trying to be strict with my code which requires definition for all parameters in which case the `(req, res)` parameter needs to be define.

I know that GCF uses Express under the hood but I don't think I need to import Express because of that. Are there any best practices or documentation that explains how to use typescript with GCF?

I tried using the `@google-cloud/functions-framework` package and find there are any helpful interfaces or classes to use but I cannot determine what should be the starting point of the function.

```
import GCF from '@google-cloud/functions-framework';

export const startFunction = ((req: GCF.???, res: GCF.???)): void => {
  // additional work done here
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Install the type packages for express and google-cloud, then import those types. It really isn't any different than any other 3rd party package. For packages like express that aren't written natively in typescript but have type definitions available you usually have to install them [separately](https://definitelytyped.org/).

Comment: Thank you @JaredSmith. So you suggest that I import Express as well? I just don't understand why I need to import it if is not needed if you would be build it with JavaScript [like it shows here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/helloworld/index.js)

Comment: Not express, the *type definitions for express*. Found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express). As for why you'd need the import, *you are trying to use two things that were not made to work together in unison*. You will probably have to do some work to fix the impedance mismatch at the seams, and the docs will be less valuable. Suggestion? Write it in JS first so you get it working with GCP, then worry about migrating to TS.

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you so much for your help. It's a good starting point.

Comment: If you are using firebase to run your cloud functions, the firebase tools make using Typescript reasonably straightforward. (See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript).  This might also give you an idea for what is necessary with the regular google cloud functions without firebase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the latest `@google-cloud/functions-framework` includes the function signatures now.

```
// Start writing Cloud Functions
// https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http

import { HttpFunction } from '@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/functions';

export const helloHttp: HttpFunction = (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello World`);
};
```

Comment: Looks like this is the documented way according to the github repository https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/master/docs/typescript.md

Comment: Can yo provide the full configuration, including all other files required?

Answer (score 0):

```
import type {HttpFunction} from '@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/functions';
import express, { query } from 'express';

export const main: HttpFunction =
  async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    console.log(req.query);
  }
```

in your `package.json` we'll have only dev dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.1.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
  }
```